# Laravel 3 and 4 in the same domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-3

We have a current API service running in Laravel 3, now we are developing a new API using Laravel 4.

We want to use the same domain for both applications.

Example:

```
http://api.domain.com/v1   --> /var/www/api.domain.com/htdocs/v1/public
http://api.domain.com/v2   --> /var/www/api.domain.com/htdocs/v2/public
```

What is the best way to accomplish this issue?

Comment: Creating virtual host for each API can be a solution. See this [tutorial](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/getting-started).

Comment: You cannot have more than one virtual host per domain! And the domain is the same for both versions.

Comment: You're right @Sven. Well, the other thing I can think of it is to create subdomains to each API and redirects. Maybe in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) can help you in better way in this topic.